# autossh not forwarding, regular ssh tunnel does

Tags: network, ssh

Starting autossh like so: `autossh -M 5122 -N -R 5432:localhost:5432 <user>@<myhost>`, I can't connect to localhost:5432. If I run `ssh -f <user>@<myhost> -L 5432:localhost:5432 -N -v -v`, I can.

The output from autossh:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5122 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:5122
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5122.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5122.
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:5122 forwarded to local address 127.0.0.1:5123
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:5432 forwarded to local address localhost:5432
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 5122, connect 127.0.0.1:5123
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 5432, connect localhost:5432
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

And from ssh:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5432 forwarded to remote address localhost:5432
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5432.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5432.
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

I've just recently started playing around with ssh tunneling and cannot figure out why autossh will only forward port 5122.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer, but maybe it still helps someone.

I had the same problem, turns out you need to use -L instead of -R:

```
autossh -M 5122 -L 5432:localhost:5432 <user>@<myhost>
```

Comment: Further explanation here: `-L` and `-R` do different things: `-L` forwards traffic from a port on the local machine into a port on the remote machine while `-R` does the reverse: forwards traffic from the remote machine back to the local machine. So the `autossh` and `ssh` commands in the original question were not equivalent.